# store json as a searchable python object?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I have this enormous messy site that I've loaded into my code as a json for the purpose of webscraping with scrapy: [json link](https://www.jomashop.com/graphql?query=query%20productDetail(%24urlKey%3AString%2C%24onServer%3ABoolean!)%7BproductDetail%3Aproducts(filter%3A%7Burl_key%3A%7Beq%3A%24urlKey%7D%7D)%7Bitems%7B__typename%20id%20sku%20name%20name_wout_brand%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20is_preowned%20brand_name%20brand_url%20manufacturer%20url_key%20stock_status%20out_of_stock_template%20out_of_stock_template_text%20price_promo_text%20promotext_code%20promotext_type%20promotext_value%20shipping_availability%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_question_mark_note%20model_id%20image%7Blabel%20url%20__typename%7Dupc_code%20item_variation%20media_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dbreadcrumbs%7Bpath%20categories%7Bname%20url_key%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dreview_details%7Breview_summary%20review_count%20__typename%7Drating_configurations%7Brating_attributes%20__typename%7Dshort_description%7Bhtml%20__typename%7Ddescription%7Bhtml%20__typename%7Dmoredetails%7Bdescription%20more_details%7Bgroup_id%20group_label%20group_attributes%7Battribute_id%20attribute_label%20attribute_value%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmsrp%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dcategories%7Bbreadcrumbs%7Bcategory_id%20category_name%20__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20GroupedProduct%7Bitems%7Bqty%20position%20product%7Bid%20sku%20stock_status%20name%20brand_name%20name_wout_brand%20manufacturer%20manufacturer_text%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_availability%20url_key%20is_preowned%20preowned_item_condition%20preowned_item_condition_text%20preowned_box%20preowned_papers%20preowned_papers_year%20preowned_condition_description%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20shipping_question_mark_note%20model_id%20msrp%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmedia_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dmoredetails%7Bdescription%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20ConfigurableProduct%7Bconfigurable_options%7Battribute_code%20attribute_id%20id%20label%20values%7Bdefault_label%20label%20store_label%20use_default_value%20value_index%20swatch_data%7Btype%20value...%20on%20ImageSwatchData%7Bthumbnail%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dvariants%7Battributes%7Bcode%20value_index%20label%20__typename%7Dproduct%7Bid%20brand_name%20brand_url%20manufacturer%20shipping_availability%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_question_mark_note%20name_wout_brand%20msrp%20price_promo_text%20promotext_code%20promotext_type%20promotext_value%20is_preowned%20model_id%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmedia_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dsku%20stock_status%20moredetails%7Bdescription%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20GiftCardProduct%7Ballow_open_amount%20open_amount_min%20open_amount_max%20giftcard_type%20is_redeemable%20lifetime%20allow_message%20message_max_length%20giftcard_amounts%7Bvalue_id%20website_id%20website_value%20attribute_id%20value%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dmeta_title%40include(if%3A%24onServer)meta_keyword%40include(if%3A%24onServer)meta_description%40include(if%3A%24onServer)canonical_url%40include(if%3A%24onServer)%7D__typename%7D%7D&operationName=productDetail&variables=%7B%22urlKey%22%3A%22bulova-watch-96b251%22%2C%22onServer%22%3Atrue%7D)

I'd like to store this json so I can access the attribute_labels and attribute_values stored in the group_attribute sub-set. But this is heavily nested, so iterating through the json is way too computationally intensive. My end goal is to be able to use some SQL-type logic, like "where attribute_label='series' get attribute_value". I have similar logic elsewhere in my code but again, it won't work here for how heavily nested it is. Any advice or ideas is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I work with JSON in python I just use the `json` library

```py
import requests,json

url = 'your_url'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

#print(json.dumps(data,indent=2)) # This will prettyprint the json

items = data['data']['productDetail']['items']

for item in items:
    print(item['id'])
```

I don't think this is that hard for the computer to iterate over. If you find the pattern that the system is following then you just go to the place in the json that you need to be and then you perform the search.

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/), a query language for JSON. It has a [Python library.](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/)

Here is an example from the Readme:

```
>>> import jmespath
>>> expression = jmespath.compile('foo.bar')
>>> expression.search({'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}})
'baz'
>>> expression.search({'foo': {'bar': 'other'}})
'other'
```